# CSS Border-radius to create curved shape

Tags: html, css, shapes, border-radius

I want to create this shape, (see attached image) using HTML CSS.

I am using these values but got not similar results.

```
 border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50% / 70% 60% 20% 20%;
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this link help? https://www.shapedivider.app/ . I don't think border radius can create that shape

Comment: What value are you using? Please post your code.

Comment: height: 640px;
 border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50% / 70% 60% 20% 20%;

Comment: Are you sure the original source isn't using an image with that curve built into it? Because that doesn't look like a shape with border-radius applied. (It'd have to be an absolutely *giant* circle to get that curvature!)

Answer (score 4):

You can also try with this approach way by giving `border-bottom` CSS properties to container:

```
.curve-style {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 200px; 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 200px; 
  width: 160%; overflow: hidden; 
  margin-bottom: -50px; 
  position: relative; 
  left:-30%; 
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this in CSS?

```
    img {
        border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using **border-radius** options.

check this line of code out : `border-radius: 0 0 60% 60% / 10%;`